# Extracting web page content with Java and XPath

Tags: java, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract a `org.w3c.dom.NodeList` from http://www.amazon.com/gp/bestsellers/electronics in Java. Here's the XPath statement I used to display the results I'm after in the Google Chrome JavaScript console:

`$x("//div[@class='zg_itemRightDiv_normal']")`

The above statement worked flawlessly, but when I use Java's `javax.xml.xpath` and `org.w3c.dom` libraries, I get no results:

```
XPathExpression expr = xPath.compile("//div[@class='zg_itemRightDiv_normal']");
NodeList productNodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

// In the above productNodes definition, doc is a org.w3c.dom.DocumentFragment

System.out.println(productNodes.getLength()); // prints out '0'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Try giving the complete path....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem ended up being twofold:

1. The `DocumentFragment` I was reading from didn't include the information I was attempting to extract; using the full `Document` solved the issue
2. For some reason, capitalizing the HTML tags in my XPath statements allowed me to acquire the information I was after (i.e., `xPath.compile("//DIV[@class='zg_itemRightDiv_normal']")`).

Answer (score 1):

It might be because you are trying to treat the input as XML when it is really HTML (and not XHTML).

You will need to convert the HTML to XHTML first - I have used [TagSoup](http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) for this successfully before but there are also other libraries that can do this (JTidy, NekoHTML).

TagSoup will give you a SAX parser, which you can then turn into a DOM and then process with XPath.